# Form for each object in list - ThymeLeaf

Tags: java, spring, jsp, thymeleaf

I am trying to make for each object in my list modal that contains a form with that object data.

So I have in my **controller**:

```
model.addAttribute("eventsInList", eventsInList);
```

and in my ThymeLeaf **template**:

```
<div th:each="evnt,intr : ${eventsInList}">
   <div class="modal fade" th:id="'modal-' + ${evnt.getId()}">
     // some content
      <form th:action="@{/updateEvent}" th:object="${evnt}" method="POST">
         <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right datepicker"
                           th:value="${evnt.getDate()}"
                           th:field="*{date}">
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

When I run this code it **throws**:

> Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'evnt' available as  request attribute

---

So I tried this:

**controller**:

```
model.addAttribute("eventsInList", eventsInList); // list of CalendarEvent
model.addAttribute("editEvent", new CalendarEvent());
```

ThymeLeaf **template**:

```
<div th:each="evnt,intr : ${eventsInList}">
   <div class="modal fade" th:id="'modal-' + ${evnt.getId()}">
     // some content
      <form th:action="@{/updateEvent}" th:object="${editEvent}" method="POST">
         <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right datepicker"
                           th:value="${evnt.getDate()}"
                           th:field="*{date}">
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

This case does not throw any exception, but `th:value="${evnt.getDate()}"` is **null**

And confusing for me is that the row `<div class="modal fade" th:id="'modal-' + ${evnt.getId()}">` normally works.

So is there any solution for this problem?

Thanks for your help all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours, I made it!

So here is my solution (works for me):

my **controller**:

```
model.addAttribute("eventsInList", eventsInList); // list of CalendarEvent
```

my ThymeLeaf **template**:

```
<div th:each="evnt, intr : ${eventsInList.getEvents()}">
   <div class="modal fade" th:id="'modal-' + ${evnt.getId()}">
     // some content
      <form th:action="@{/updateEvent}" th:object="${eventsInList[__${intr.index}__]}" method="POST">
         <input type="text"
                th:value="${eventsInList[__${intr.index}__].getDate()}"
                th:name="|date|">
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I didn't use `th:field=""` it's because in this case the `th:field` **does not work**, but there is another solution to bind input with `th:object` and that is that you can use `th:name` which bind input value with `th:object`.

For more info, you can read [this](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Generating-form-using-th-each-td4027917.html)